# Drive 2 7-Segment Displays with one register

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, avr

in an effort to learn some low level AVR-c, I a trying to learn how to how to drive 2 7-Segment displays with 2 pins and power both from 7 pins (in theory). All seven segments of both displays are driven by the same port (PortC).

I am using [this tutorial](http://www.avr-tutorials.com/projects/atmega16-based-digital-clock) as a guide. My version is much simpler for the learning exercise. I have attached a crude schematic (please for give me!) and my code.

Based on how my displays are wired up, that is, the Common Cathode on Segment1 and Segment2 are connected to PINs A0 and A1 (PC0/PC1). When these PINS go low, the circuit is complete and the LEDs light up.

In the tutorial, they have the Anodes (A-G) of each segment LED connected in series and use 6 pins to drive the 7 displays. In mine, I only have 2 displays.

How can I achieve this?

[image: 2-7 Segment Display]

```
#include "avr/delay.h"

void setLedPorts (uint8_t dig);

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    DDRD |= 0b11111100;
    DDRB |= 0b00000011;
    DDRC |= 0b00000011; // Control port A0 / PC0 && A2 / PC1


}

void loop()
{
    uint8_t cmask = 0b11111100;
    while(1)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){

            setLedPorts(i/10);
            PORTC = ~(0x01);

            //setLedPorts(i%10);// when I uncomment these to lines, Segment2 only works         
            //PORTC = ~(0x02);

            _delay_ms(100);
        }
    }
}


void setLedPorts (uint8_t dig){
    uint8_t dmask = 0b00000011;
    uint8_t bmask = 0b11111100;
    switch (dig)
    {

        case 0:

        PORTD = 0b10111100 & ~dmask;
        PORTB = 0b00000011 & ~bmask;
        break;
        case 1:
        PORTD = 0b00001000 & ~dmask;
        PORTB = 0b00000010 & ~bmask;
        break;
        case 2:
        PORTD = 0b11110000 & ~dmask;
        PORTB = 0b00000011 & ~bmask;
        break;
        case 3:
        PORTD = 0b1011000 & ~dmask;
        PORTB = 0b00000011 & ~bmask;
        break;
        case 4:
        PORTD = 0b01001100 & ~dmask;
        PORTB = 0b00000010 & ~bmask;
        break;
        case 5:
        PORTD = 0b11011100 & ~dmask;
        PORTB = 0b00000001 & ~bmask;
        break;
        case 6:
        PORTD = 0b11111100 & ~dmask;
        PORTB = 0b00000001 & ~bmask;
        break;
        case 7:
        PORTD = 0b10001000 & ~dmask;
        PORTB = 0b00000011 & ~bmask;
        break;
        case 8:
        PORTD = 0b11111100 & ~dmask;
        PORTB = 0b00000011 & ~bmask;
        break;
        case 9:
        PORTD = 0b11001100 & ~dmask;
        PORTB = 0b00000011 & ~bmask;
        break;
        default:
        PORTD = 0b11111100 & ~dmask;
        PORTB = 0b00000011 & ~bmask;
        break;
    }

}
```

**Edit**

I almost got it. By changing my while loop to:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    setLedPorts(i/10);      
    PORTC = ~(0x01);                    
    _delay_ms(10);      
    setLedPorts(i%10);
    PORTC = ~(0x02); 
    _delay_ms(1000);
}
```

Segment1, displays the first digit, but flashes. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was a bit confused after trying to read the diagram and the text. Don't try to look at the details of a circuit and/or program. You'll get lost in no time.

If you want to see all possible numbers, you need all the segments. That means 7 segments (8 if you want the decimal point too), so you need 7 (or 8) bits of a port. And then two more ports bits for the digit cathodes.

To multiplex two common cathode displays the hardware must be like this:

- connect the corresponding segments (i.e. A-G) together
- connect them to 7 lines of the register/port you want to use
- use two lines, one for each of the cathodes.

To be correct, you should limit the current in each of the segments with a resistor, but for an experiment, you could get away with the internal limitation of the processor.

Then, the software should do this:

Initialize:

- set all used bits (segments and cathodes) to 1
- set all ports as outputs

Loop:

- Set the bits you want to light on display 1 to 1
- Set the bit for display 1 to low (the display should show the number)
- Wait for a bit, say 10ms
- Switch the bit for display 1 to high (off)
- Set the bits you want to light on display 2 to 1
- Set the bit for display 2 to low (the display should show the number)
- Wait for a bit, say 10ms
- Switch the bit for display 2 to high (off)
- Go to loop.

Comment: Thanks - see my edit. I tried your suggestion. I am almost there. The first digit displays a number but flashes. How do I keep the number from flashing?

Comment: Visibly flashing means there is something in your program which is slow enough to cause it. Are you calling the right delay routines? Is the second digit appearing (maybe the digit is flashing because the second number is not appearing)? Note that, at 2 times 10ms (i.e. 50 times per second), very little flashing should appear.